# laravel-mix - JS destination files put in the wrong path

Tags: javascript, css, laravel-mix

Running through the Concrete CMS tutorial for the flintstones theme [here](https://documentation.concretecms.org/developers/pages-themes/working-themes/building-theme-concrete-bedrock/setup-development-environment) throws up a problem where if I place the source js and css files in a /Documents/.. development folder and the site is served by MAMP the CSS files go to the right folder but the JS files do not.

webpack.mix.js includes:

```
var publicDir = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dlm/application/themes/flintstone';
mix.setPublicPath(publicDir);

mix
    .sass('assets/scss/main.scss', 'css/main.css')
    .js('assets/js/main.js', '/js/main.js');
```

This puts the CSS in the right place:
'/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dlm/application/themes/flintstone/css/main.css'

But the JS files are put here:
/Applications/MAMP/dlm/htdocs/application/themes/flintstone/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dlm/application/themes/flintstone/js/main.js

It seems the JS side cannot take a root folder redirection.  Can anyone shed any light on it please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looked a bit further into webpack.mix.js and found an answer:

```
var publicDir = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dlm/application/themes/flintstone';
mix.setPublicPath(publicDir);

mix
    .webpackConfig({
        output: {
            filename:'js/main.js',
            path: '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dlm/application/themes/flintstone',
        },
    })
    .sass('assets/scss/main.scss', 'css/main.css')
    .js('assets/js/main.js', 'js/main.js');
```

This appears to be putting both main.css and main.js into the correct folders and the Concrete theme appears to be building correctly.

As I understand it, the webpackConfig overrides the 'output' file aspect of the .js('assets/js/main.js', 'js/main.js'); line.

If I replace the webpackConfig .filename with 'js/[name].js', the destination then includes the path again creating 'js/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dlm/application/themes/flintstone/main.js'.

Hope this helps.